# Iterating over an optional using enumerated

Tags: swift, swiftui

Having problems iterating through an optional enumerated type. Looking for *general guidance* if anyone has any and **will post any code if needed.**

It all stems from this

```
@Published var movielist: Movie?
```

but I'm really confused on how to handle this error.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(vm.movielist?.results ?? []).enumerated()`

This way, if `vm.movielist` is nil, then an empty collection gets used instead.

(this is the first "Fix" solution that Xcode gives, although sometimes it gets the syntax a little bit funny when it tries to fix things automatically that are in a chain like this)